# Ant failed when I run ant runtime in $NUTCH_HOME

Tags: java, ant, nutch

Ant failed when I run ant runtime in **$NUTCH_HOME**, error information:

***BUILD FAILED***

> /home/gannyee/nutch/build.xml:69: Directory /home/gannyee/nutch/build
>   creation was not successful for an unknown reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems an file write permission issue, either try running command with sudo Or give the folder write permission. hth.